# Removing dynamic list of strings from Oracle table

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have an Oracle table with customers and a column containing a string comma-separated list of products that they have purchased, ie

| customers | products |
| --- | --- |
| cust_a | prod_a,prod_b,prod_c |
| cust_b | prod_b,prod_d,prod_f |

I also have as a query
`select products_to_remove from ...` that returns

| products_to_remove |
| --- |
| prod_b |
| prod_c |

How can I build a new table or update the original table to remove all the strings returned from the *products_to_remove* query from the original table to get

| customers | products |
| --- | --- |
| cust_a | prod_a |
| cust_b | prod_d,prod_f |

I know how to hard-code the *products_to_remove* values and remove/format them from the table, but I was hoping there might be a better and more adaptable Oracle SQL solution so I can do the removal on a larger scale for a few different cases.

Comment: Don't use comma-separated lists in SQL. Normalize the purchases table to put each product in its own row.

Comment: Then you can simply delete the rows that match the rows
 in `products_to_remove`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store delimited strings.

Have a separate `customer_products` table and **store** each customer/product pair in a separate row. If you want to **display** products as a delimited list then use `LISTAGG` to generate the delimited list.

---

As an academic exercise, it is possible to remove items from a delimited list; however, really don't use this. Properly normalise your data and store each product in a separate row.

If you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dont_store_delimited_strings (customers, products) AS
SELECT 'cust_a', 'prod_a,prod_b,prod_c' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'cust_b', 'prod_b,prod_d,prod_f' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE really_dont (products_to_remove) AS
SELECT 'prod_b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'prod_c' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can use:

```sql
MERGE INTO dont_store_delimited_strings dst
USING (
  WITH indexed_removal (ptr, idx, max_idx) AS (
    SELECT products_to_remove, ROWNUM, COUNT(*) OVER ()
    FROM   really_dont
  ),
  removed (rid, products, lvl, max_lvl) AS (
    SELECT s.ROWID,
           REPLACE(',' || s.products || ',', ',' || i.ptr || ',', ','),
           i.idx,
           i.max_idx
    FROM   dont_store_delimited_strings s
           INNER JOIN indexed_removal i
           ON (i.idx = 1)
  UNION ALL
    SELECT r.rid,
           REPLACE(r.products, ',' || i.ptr || ',', ','),
           i.idx,
           r.max_lvl
    FROM   removed r
           INNER JOIN indexed_removal i
           ON (r.lvl + 1 = i.idx)
  )
  SELECT rid,
         TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM products) AS products
  FROM   removed
  WHERE  lvl = max_lvl
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET products = src.products;
```

Which, after the `MERGE` then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dont_store_delimited_strings;
```

Outputs:

| CUSTOMERS | PRODUCTS |
| --- | --- |
| cust_a | prod_a |
| cust_b | prod_d,prod_f |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_dq6CZWV)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yeah, I know this is an awful way to store data, but unfortunately, it's not really my call. There's a ton of spreadsheets that pull from these old tables, and the manager  of this department wants to keep the db as is

Answer (score 1):

That's not a good normalization. You will need at least three tables to implement a many to many relationship, I think four: `customer(id,name,...)`, `product(id,name,...)`, `sale(id,customer,...)`, `product_in_sale(sale,product,...)`. I don't use Oracle to create the corrects DDLs but this is a modelling problem.